# In Powershell, how do I use Compare-Object based on one property but output all properties?

Tags: powershell, compareobject

Here is an example of log file inputs which contains MD5 hash and filename (with file size and date time stamp which is fine, what I want).

hashlog1.log:

```
2E331B30A705D462541398874451A955 \steamapps\appmanifest_1036890.acf 798 20230919_003055
D9A3D74B9F48CC599406F1D74D293261 \steamapps\appmanifest_1046030.acf 795 20231021_213325
2C364B22B4866903ED5E3BD9740B9DFA \steamapps\appmanifest_1086410.acf 762 20230413_034326
88D100F2A7FFC2C912B59B45AED9DC48 \steamapps\appmanifest_1091500.acf 925 20231026_112000
2A03A13E570CDA7424216DEF84C958EA \steamapps\appmanifest_1151640.acf 901 20230512_235832
```

hashlog2.log:

```
97CAF30C2E1F73ED121F75D947DB29C3 \steamapps\appmanifest_1036890.acf 798 20231122_123455
D9A3D74B9F48CC599406F1D74D293261 \steamapps\appmanifest_1046030.acf 795 20231021_213325
2C364B22B4866903ED5E3BD9740B9DFA \steamapps\appmanifest_1086410.acf 762 20230413_034326
78CF976F8BA64DAF19319E84B8133598 \steamapps\appmanifest_1091500.acf 687 20231122_125522
2A03A13E570CDA7424216DEF84C958EA \steamapps\appmanifest_1151640.acf 901 20230512_235832
```

I generate new tables with column headers:

```
$file1=(Get-Content -Path "hashlog1.log") | Select @{N='Hash'; E={($_ -split ' ',2)[0]}},@{N='File'; E={(($_ -split ' ',2)[1])}}
$file2=(Get-Content -Path "hashlog2.log") | Select @{N='Hash'; E={($_ -split ' ',2)[0]}},@{N='File'; E={(($_ -split ' ',2)[1])}}
```

I want to compare based on the filename only ("File"). But I would like to output both "Hash" and "File" values in the output.

If I use:

```
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property File | Select Hash,File,SideIndicator
```

It seems I should be able to get the proper output but it's only showing the "File" and "SideIndicator" property values, not "Hash"

```
Hash File                                                   SideIndicator
---- ----                                                   -------------
     \steamapps\appmanifest_1036890.acf 798 20231122_123455 =>
     \steamapps\appmanifest_1091500.acf 687 20231122_125522 =>
     \steamapps\appmanifest_1036890.acf 798 20230919_003055 <=
     \steamapps\appmanifest_1091500.acf 925 20231026_112000 <=
```

How do I get it to also output the Hash value as well? Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property File, Hash` ?

Comment: `-PassThru` passes the original input objects through, irrespective of the comparison property/ies specified via `-Property`. The caveat is that if you also use `-IncludeEqual`, it is only ever the _LHS_ object that is passed through. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 -Property File -PassThru

Comment: Well dang. I guess I missed the '-PassThru' flag. Seems to work. SMH. Thanks for the prompt response!